# What is MONITORING in Toad generated code snippet for a Table (create table)?

Tags: toad, oracle11gr2

I created a table named test_tbl in oracle as following. After table is created I analysed the DDL statement from toad it has one physical properties named MONITORING? 
What is the use of this MONITORING clause?

```sql
create table test_tbl
(
    col_a number(5,0),
    col_b varchar2(30)
);
```

This is the code generated from TOAD (schema browser --> Script)

```sql
DROP TABLE MEERAN.TEST_TBL CASCADE CONSTRAINTS;

CREATE TABLE MEERAN.TEST_TBL
(
  COL_A  NUMBER(5),
  COL_B  VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)
)
TABLESPACE PANAMA_TS
PCTUSED    0
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   1
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            INITIAL          64K
            NEXT             1M
            MINEXTENTS       1
            MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
           )
LOGGING 
NOCOMPRESS 
NOCACHE
MONITORING;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a deprecated clause; [from the 10gR2 docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#i2215263):

> **MONITORING | NOMONITORING**
>
> In earlier releases, you could use these clauses to start or stop the collection of modification statistics on this table. These clauses have been deprecated.
>
> - If you formerly collected modification statistics on tables by using the `DBMS_STATS` package in `GATHER AUTO` or `GATHER STALE` mode, then you no longer have to do anything. Oracle Database now collects these statistics automatically, and the `MONITORING` and `NOMONITORING` keywords in existing code will not cause an error.
> - If, for performance reasons, you do not want to collect modification statistics on any tables, then you should set the `STATISTICS_LEVEL` initialization parameter to `BASIC`. Be aware, however, that doing so disables a number of manageability features.

This clause isn't even mentioned in later versions of that documentation; and `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` doesn't include it when run against an 11gR2 table for me - at least with default settings. There is still a `monitoring` column in `all_tables` though.

The 11g+ documentation [also says](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables005.htm#ADMIN11656):

> Formerly, you enabled `DBMS_STATS` to automatically gather statistics for a table by specifying the `MONITORING` keyword in the `CREATE` (or `ALTER`) `TABLE` statement. Starting with Oracle Database 11g, the `MONITORING` and `NOMONITORING` keywords have been deprecated and statistics are collected automatically. If you do specify these keywords, they are ignored.

It seems that Toad is reconstructing the DDL manually from the data dictionary rather than using that package - the clause order and lack of double-quotes around the schema and table names also suggest that is the case. If you want to change what is included, [see this Quest knowledge base article](https://support.quest.com/toad-for-oracle/kb/152561/how-to-disable-storage-parameter-default-settings-in-table-rebuild-generated-script-).

But basically, you can just ignore `MONITORING`, since Oracle will.

Comment: Thanks! as the document says USER_TAB_MODIFICATIONS collects the statistics, but no statistics available (I am using Oracle XE - Express Edition)